# connecting to the internet through mac os x lion virtual machine on windows 7

Tags: windows, macos, mac, virtual-machine, osx-lion

I've followed a video tutorial and managed to set up a mac os x lion installation on my oracle Virtual Machine. I'm running windows 7 on the actual machine.

When I try to connect to the internet through the mac virtual machine it tells me I'm not connected. For the other virtual machines I used I didn't have to do anything to connect, internet was just available. Same for the android emulator I use, didn't have to set anything up for that.

Anyway, I haven't a clue what to do. If I click on network diagnostics I get asked for settings about my network port config. I'm not sure what to do here. The only error I got when I installed was along the lines "system extension cannot be used" the system extension "/system/library/extension/RT61cardBusDriver.kext" was installed improperly and cannot be used

Not sure what this is either though.

My internet connection is just a 3g mobile dongle.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Oracle VirtualBox I assume?

Comment: @siebz0r Yeah, oracle virtual box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox offers many ways to set up networking. If you want to have internet access you can try bridging or NAT. The easiest in my opinion is NAT.

Go to your virtual machine's settings and click on "Network". Then check if the adapter is enabled and select "NAT" from the dropdown list. It should look something like [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/images/computers_new_1/virtualbox-network-nat-new.png).

Comment: I had read something to do with changing it to NAT and had looked for ages on the virtual mac to find how to set it. Never occurred to me that it was set in Oracle VM until I saw your picture. Thanks so much :)